# How to define a property synonyme in an object?

Tags: javascript

I have defined a property in a javascript object like this

```
function obj()
{
      this.elems = [1,2,3]
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
          get: function() { 
              return this.elems.length; 
          }
      });
}
```

Until now, everything works fine, and I have defined a function that takes two arguments, a property name and its synonym

```
this.defineSyn = function(property,syn) 
{
      Object.defineProperty(this, syn, function() { 
          return this[property]; 
      });
}
```

now inside the object definition I call the `defineSyn` function like this

`this.defineSyn('length','len');`

but when I declare a variable and try to call the property `len`, I get '`undefined`' as result while `length` returns as result `3`

```
var o = new obj();
console.log(o.length); // returns 3
console.log(o.len); // returns undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `defineProperty()` call is bad within `defineSym()`:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, syn , function() { return this[property]; });
```

This should be:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, syn , { get: function() { return this[property]; } });
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent a lot of time to solve this and didn't notice the arguments of `defineProperty`